# typescript generic function not recognizing type guards with ts-node

Tags: typescript, ts-node, ajv

I am trying to implement a generic validation function. Below is a very simple minimal version of the code:

```js
import Ajv, { JSONSchemaType } from 'ajv'

export function validate<T>(body: string, schema: JSONSchemaType<T>): T {
  const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true })
  const validateSchema = ajv.compile(schema)

  const parsed: unknown = JSON.parse(body)

  if (validateSchema(parsed)) { // <-- this is a type guard for type T
    return parsed               // <-- VS code recognizes this as type T
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Could not validate ${parsed}.`)
  }
}
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQQFYDcA0cDecBSBlAeQDk8BjACwFMQBDAFQE8xK4BfOAMyghDgHIaqPgChhlAB6RYnAK4A7UjGAQ5cFDQA2wACY0YlADx0AfAAoARhG0MAXHADOMKMDkBzDPYrUad-MTJUtIzMRsYAlHZ0WMJwcKQqjnCCKHAAvHBylADuiKim2JoaAKJQ3FD2dk4yLKxhMXEJ8OpauvoB3mlJqAB08eDAGpSmnoE0dfXxcolgNOWU2nbyANZyEFmq6X5E3TNzFlYM47HAHHCmzTp6lO20prv282FhWHAA9K9wBgC0X3Aw5MB7HBAUk-kwWK4ZLNtJxoGDmHA6PVYlBKDAZFBVPd5rFcXj8W8Pt9fgA1PANbQsVHxVxyYAAL0oQP+IJozPBiPq7EoGge0Tx-24OUyORKZVMAAMAMIQGQaGGrJqaS76OAAEkw2O0rG6ErqsVYwkNQA)

When trying to run this code via `ts-node`, it complains:

> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.

However, the typescript inference engine in VS code correctly recognizes the type guard.

[Screenshot of VS code showing type guard working correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUGip.png)

In fact, if I move that code into a folder where `Ajv` is not resolved (and so the type guard is not recognized), then VS code shows me the same error as `ts-node`.

---

How can I get `ts-node` to recognize the type guard? Is this a bug with `ts-node`?

Comment: Sounds like the type information for `Ajv` isn't available in the `ts-node` environment where you're having the issue?

Comment: FYI in the future you can add code to [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to show type information as opposed to taking a screenshot. TS Playground will even pull in type information from npm packages. I've added one for you.

Comment: I have a bunch of questions for more information that may or may not help. What TypeScript version are you using? What `ts-node` version are you using? What does your `tsconfig` look like? Are you passing in any special configurations for anything? If you run TypeScript on the command line (`tsc`), is there anything notable?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a niche question but it might help someone else. For me, upgrading typescript to the latest version worked. The previous version was `~3.9.7` and now it's `4.5.4`.

```sh
yarn add --dev typescript@latest
```